# Moving average for continuous functions

Tags: mean, continuous-data, moving-average

In statistics, the moving average is usually defined for discrete data sets. Is there a moving average concept for continuous randomly fast-oscillating functions? I am seeking for the moving average determined in terms of integrals rather than sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the mean value of the function in each window.

A "backward-looking" moving average with window size $w$ is
$$
\mbox{MA}_w^\text{b}(t) = \frac{1}{w} \int_{t-w}^t f(x)dx ,
$$
and a "centered" moving average is
$$
\mbox{MA}_w^\text{c}(t) = \frac{1}{w} \int_{t-w/2}^{t+w/2} f(x)dx .
$$

Comment: Seems nice! Do you have a reference to a textbook or paper where this definition is utilized?

Comment: I don't have a reference where the suggested function is used to compute the moving average; I just customized the [first mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration) to your needs.